# Get css height of component B, zero if component B has not mounted

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, react-hooks

I have two react components, component A and component B

component B has `height: 90px;`

component A has `height: calc(100vh - 90px);`

when the page loads, component B is not in the DOM, it will get rendered and will appear on screen when the user clicks something

I want component A to have `height: calc(100vh);` if component B is not in the DOM or not visible and I want component A to have `height: calc(100vh -90px);` when component B is mounted or visible

How do I achieve that? Can I do it with hooks and without `document.get`?

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Main = () => {

useEffect(() => {
// i try to update Component A height here, 
// but this block doesnt get called when Component B is mounted
}, [])

return (
      <div className={style.Main}>
        <Router>
          <ComponentA/>
          <ComponentB/>
          ...
        </Router>
      </div>
)

}
export default Main;
```

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';

const ComponentB = () => {

useEffect(() => {
// need a way to update Component A height that isnt `document.getelem`
}, [clicked])

return (...)

}
export default ComponentB;
```

**EDIT**
parent div is a css grid

```
.Main {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
gap: 0px 0px;
grid-template-areas:
        "componentA Header"
        "componentA Body"
        "componentB componentB";
}
```

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet of what you tried

Comment: @SuperDJ added some

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach you can consider. I have used background color to highlight the change in height of components.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const CompA = ({style, updateStyle}) => {
  return  <div style={style}>
    <h2>Component A</h2>
    <button onClick={updateStyle}>Update Height</button>
  </div>
}

const CompB = () => {
  return  <div style={{height:'90px', backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
    <h2>Component B</h2>
  </div>
}
function App() {
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = useState(false);
  const [defaultStyle, setDefaultStyle] = useState({
    height:'100vh',
    background:'red'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if(btnClicked) {
      setDefaultStyle({height:`calc(100vh - 90px)`,background:'yellow'})
    }

  }, [btnClicked])

  return (
    <div>
      <CompA style={defaultStyle} updateStyle={()=>setBtnClicked(true)}/>
      { btnClicked && <CompB /> }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```